Hazelcast Jet Pipeline Only Running on One Node in Multi-Node Cluster
I've been trying to run a Hazelcast Jet pipeline across multiple nodes to fully utilize my machine resources. However, it seems like the job is only running on one node.
Here is my pipeline code:
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

BatchSource<String> source = SourceBuilder.batch("test-source", context -> new DataReader())
        .<String>fillBufferFn(DataReader::fillBuffer)
        .destroyFn(DataReader::destroy)
        .build();

pipeline.readFrom(source)
        .mapUsingServiceAsync(ServiceFactories.sharedService(ctx -> new AESDecryptionService("xxxxxx")), AESDecryptionService::decryptAsync).setName("AESDecryptionService")
        .writeTo(Sinks.logger());

hazelcastInstance.getJet().newJob(pipeline);

Here is the digraph DAG:
digraph DAG {
    "test-source" [localParallelism=1];
    "AESDecryptionService" [localParallelism=4];
    "loggerSink" [localParallelism=1];
    "test-source" -> "AESDecryptionService" [queueSize=4];
    "AESDecryptionService" -> "loggerSink" [queueSize=4];
}

I wonder if I might have missed some configuration or option that causes the sub-tasks in the DAG to not be distributed across multiple nodes (if I understand the official documentation correctly)?
Any insights or suggestions on how to ensure my Hazelcast Jet pipeline runs efficiently across all nodes in the cluster would be greatly appreciated!

Each node of the DAG can run on a different member. The DAG does not indicate which member it is. It only shows the local parallelism value on that member.
